# Upgrade Codeigniter 3.1.6 to 4.1.9

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I have a admin panel made with Codeigniter 3.1.6 version. I searched it but i found different opinions about it.  Can i upgrade it to 4.1.9? I have site settings, image uploading, mail sending and some different things in my project. (iziToast, sweetalert, toggle button)

Comment: CI3 and CI4 have completely different structure. You will need to extensively rework on your existing project to convert it to version 4.x

Comment: as pointed out by @DhavalChheda, you'll need to do a major re-write. I've done it and it takes some time. The main change are with your CI-libraries, here the list of changes: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html#upgrading-libraries

Comment: Likewise I have done it and it does take some time but once you've upgraded, you at least have CI4 ready code. Thing to bear in mind is how long CI3 will be supported. IMHO its better to upgrade before you build lots of new things / features otherwise you'll have to upgrade them all later anyway. Worth bearing in mind server requirements for CI4 are different (i.e. PHP 7.x +) so its worth just planning for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a big endeavor but nonetheless - this should give you some structure and pointers - [Upgrading CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html)

While most is generally to Filetype (Model, View or Controller) and specific upgrade and/or omissions of libraries and in few areas extensive changes might be needed in your code.

Most of the changes must be from Models as more of CRUD Functionality is built-in available, while Configuration Files is completely different than CodeIgniter 3. I believe part by part some areas might be tricky.
Wishing success ahead with new features and Built in ORM.

P.S. - Myself am beginner in CodeIgniter 4 only.

Comment: Should I upgrade to Codeigniter 4? Is there a huge change for me to use Codeigniter 4?
I'm thinking of doing an e-commerce project with Codeigniter 3
 Thanks.